# Phonegap Ajax method POST error 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, http-status-code-404, phonegap-plugins

Phonegap ajax with method `GET` running fine but with `POST` giving error. I have tried with `cordova-plugin-whitelist` but no luck still giving error 404 not found.

Here is my ajax code

```
function GetSlider(){
    serverRoot = "/js/ajax.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: serverRoot,
        data: "act=GetSlider",
        dataType: "JSON",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loading").show();
        },
        success: function(){
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });         
}
```

config.xml

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-navigation href="dubailibrary.com*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeWBP.png)

In Response: **`Cannot POST /js/ajax.php`**

Comment: You are calling a local php file, this can‘t work. You have to use a remote server, e.g. www.example.com/js/ajax.php

Comment: Thanks Joerg that worked. But is there any solution that it work on local?

Comment: You can't run php on a phonegap app, you need a server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Content Security Policy method: [Cordova Plugin Whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#network-request-whitelist)